# javafx maximized window moves if dialog shows up

Tags: java, linux, javafx, window, modality

If I create a javafx dialog using the following method:

```
public static void showDialog(Event event) throws IOException {
    dialogStage = new Stage();
    GridPane grid = (GridPane) Start.createLoader().load(Start.class.getResource("file.fxml").openStream());
    dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(grid));
    dialogStage.setTitle("Title");
    dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    dialogStage.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
    dialogStage.showAndWait();
}
```

the ower window moves in case it is maximized. This also happens if I use:

```
Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL
```

It works if I combine:

```
dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage.getOwner());
```

but in this case the owner window is not blocked.
I want my dialog showing up on a maximized window without moving it. The maximized window should be blocked while the dialog is open. How can I do this?

Btw. I am using java 8 and javafx on linux.

Tanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `owner window moves in case it is maximized` ? I am not sure if its the case because of Linux, but I am sure in windows and Mac, `Modality.WINDOW_MODAL` will block the parent window. Please refer [here for more information](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html)

Comment: As shown in the first listing I use Modality.WINDOW_MODAL and it blocks the parent window as expected. There is no problem if the parent window doesn't use the whole screen size (not fullsize) but if it uses the whole screen size the parent window moves a bit on the screen (to the right and down) before showing the dialog. As the parent window stays the same size, part of the parent window moves out of the screen.

Comment: Well, I can't replicate the situation in my MAC. How are you resizing the parent window to use the whole screen ? If you are resizing it by setting the size, you may try `stage.setMaximized(true);` in your parentStage !

Comment: thanks for your efforts! The user sets the size of the window and even if I set maximized in the code it doesn't help. I'll try on windows OS later. It's probably a linux specific thing.

Comment: It definitly seems to be a linux specific problem because I can observe the same problem using the javafxSceneBuiler 2.0 under linux. Some dialogs causing the same behavior there.

Comment: If you find this as an issue in javafx, please file an issue in [javafx jira](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/)

Comment: issue still present

Comment: here is the bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8255347 still not fixed

Comment: my friend with Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73593523/why-doesnt-my-friend-have-this-bug-while-i-am

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for Linux it's possible to use this trick:

```
  stage.setMaximized(true);
  if (PlatformUtil.isLinux()) {
    stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        stage.removeEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, this);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
          var bounds = new Rectangle2D(stage.getX(), stage.getY(), stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());
          stage.setMaximized(false);
          stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
          stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
          stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
          stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
          stage.setMaximized(true);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found another solution that works pretty fine on Linux. It uses a trick: if the user restores the window from the maximized state manually by double clicking on the title, and then maximizes it again by double clicking on the title, this bug is not reproduced anymore.
To emulate double clicking I use the Robot:

```
stage.setMaximized(true);                                                                             
if (PlatformUtil.isLinux()) { // a workaround of a bug of modal dialogs shown on top of the stage     
  stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);                                                                         
  stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<>() {                              
    @Override                                                                                         
    public void handle(WindowEvent windowEvent) {                                                     
      stage.removeEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, this);                                       
      new Thread(() -> {                                                                              
        doubleClick();                                                                                
        LockSupport.parkNanos(10_000_000L);                                                           
        doubleClick();                                                                                
        Platform.runLater(() -> stage.setAlwaysOnTop(false));                                         
      }).start();                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                 
                                                                                                      
    private void doubleClick() {                                                                      
      robotAction(stage, r -> r.mouseClick(MouseButton.PRIMARY));                                     
      LockSupport.parkNanos(1_000_000L);                                                              
      robotAction(stage, r -> r.mouseClick(MouseButton.PRIMARY));                                     
    }                                                                                                 
                                                                                                      
    private void robotAction(Stage stage, Consumer<Robot> action) {                                   
      var latch = new CountDownLatch(1);                                                              
      Platform.runLater(() -> {                                                                       
        try {                                                                                         
          var robot = new Robot();                                                                    
          var centerX = stage.getX() + stage.getWidth() / 2d;                                         
          robot.mouseMove(centerX, stage.getY() + 3d);                                                
          action.accept(robot);                                                                       
        } finally {                                                                                   
          latch.countDown();                                                                          
        }                                                                                             
      });                                                                                             
      try {                                                                                           
        latch.await();                                                                                
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {                                                              
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);                                                           
      }                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                 
  });                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                     
stage.show();
```